# XCode SVN Unable to commit Images.xcassets

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

My Images.xcassets list was getting long, so I decided to organize it with sub folders. Since then, I am not able to commit any changes for the `Images.xcassets` to my SVN repository. I keep getting the error:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
'filePath/gopremium.imageset/gopremium' is not under version control (1)
```

Within XCode, the `Images.xcassets` does have the M to the right indicating it has been modified, but I cant seem to see which specifics files are under version control. I thought they were added automatically, but it appears I'm wrong. Does anyone know how I can add everything in the `Images.xcassets` under version control?

**UPDATE:**

I ran the `svn st` command. The output is very long so I am posting a couple examples. Here is one from a directory I created and images which were not previous under source control

```
A       MyApp/Images.xcassets/myDirectory/F00.imageset
A       MyApp/Images.xcassets/myDirectory/F00.imageset/Contents.json
A       MyApp/Images.xcassets/myDirectory/F00.imageset/F00.png
?       MyApp/Images.xcassets/myDirectory/F00.imageset/F00@2x.png
?       MyApp/Images.xcassets/myDirectory/F00.imageset/F00@3x.png
```

Here is the output from the images which were not in a subfolder and then moved into one.

```
D       MyApp/Images.xcassets/1100-list-2-selected.imageset
D       MyApp/Images.xcassets/1100-list-2-selected.imageset/1100-list-2-selected.png
D       MyApp/Images.xcassets/1100-list-2-selected.imageset/1100-list-2-selected@2x.png
D       MyApp/Images.xcassets/1100-list-2-selected.imageset/1100-list-2-selected@3x.png
D       MyApp/Images.xcassets/1100-list-2-selected.imageset/Contents.json

A       MyApp/Images.xcassets/tabs/1100-list-2-selected.imageset
A       MyApp/Images.xcassets/tabs/1100-list-2-selected.imageset/1100-list-2-selected.png
A       MyApp/Images.xcassets/tabs/1100-list-2-selected.imageset/1100-list-2-selected@2x.png
A       MyApp/Images.xcassets/tabs/1100-list-2-selected.imageset/1100-list-2-selected@3x.png
A       MyApp/Images.xcassets/tabs/1100-list-2-selected.imageset/Contents.json
```

Comment: can you send us the result of "svn st" command from your project directory with the Terminal?

Comment: I updated the post with some output.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the GUI of the asset catalog by dragging and dropping the image. That will add your files under version control automatically. Otherwise you can run the command line svn add.
If your images are named with "@" that might cause problem adding automatically to source control. To resolve this problem you can simply remove the "@" from file names.

Comment: The strange this is that is how I always add my images. It seemed to not add all the files under version control. I was hoping to be able to do it other than command line, because there are quite a bit of image files.

Comment: I updated the answer. You can check if this will solve the problem.